# Paperclip: rake aborted for rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip

Currently, i have changed styles of my Photo class. To reflect those changes, I am trying to execute this command on ubuntu terminal:

```
 rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo
```

But it is giving error

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /var/www/example/public/system/photos/avatars/000/000/001/original/photo.jpeg
```

Actually in my system/photos/, there is no folder named '001'. And hence it is not able to find images in this folder.

I am not getting, why paperclip is considering folder which does not exists in my app.

Is there any way to get out of this error and refresh the styles?

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you paste your initializer?

Comment: @Eru hey, not getting what u mean by initializer. I dont have any paperclip related initializer.